# YouTube API v3 `getMonetizationDetails` returning null

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to acces the monetization details from within my Java application using YouTube API v3 in order to change the monetization details for particular videos.

My YouTube and Google Accounts are set up to work with Google AdSense and the monetization feature is enabled via the YouTube web frontend. Still i cannot retrieve the monetization details from `Video`. The returned `VideoMonetizationDetails` is always `null`.

```
YouTube.Videos.List listVideosRequest = M_YOUTUBE.videos().list("snippet,status").setId(_sVideoId);
VideoListResponse listResponse = listVideosRequest.execute();

List<Video> videoList = listResponse.getItems();
if (!videoList.isEmpty()) {
  Video video = videoList.get(0);
  VideoMonetizationDetails vmd = video.getMonetizationDetails();
  // vmd is null
}
```

I have tried all values for the list filter already:
  `contentDetails, fileDetails, id, liveStreamingDetails, localizations, player, processingDetails, recordingDetails, snippet, statistics, status, suggestions, topicDetails`

How do i retrieve and set monetization details for videos using the YouTube API v3?

Comment: Are you sure, that getMonetizationDetails is supported in v3 ? I wasn't able to find it in https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#resource

Comment: I see your concern. Still, why would it be a part of the Java Interface Libraries? As you can see here it is documented though (part of the video class) https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/youtube/v3/java/latest/

Comment: Did you enabled the monetization in Channel settings? to monetize a video, you must claim the video with an `asset` in the Youtube rights management system. Also, please read the [terms of service](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/api-services-terms-of-service) to ensure that your ideas don't violate the prohibited use of the YouTube APIs.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts. I guess i have enabled what you are talking about, but will double check it once i get to work on the project again next monday! Additionally, thank you for the tos information. Indeed i have not read it yet.

Comment: Hey @PAWL did you found the answer. please share your solution.